# SDL Library PNG support

Tags: c++, linux, sdl

I tried compiling the code which I downloaded from net for one gaming application.

When I do configure I get the following error :-

```
configure: error: Unable to find the SDL_image library with PNG support
```

It seem to me that I did not had any SDL library on my fedora so I did the update as below :-

```
sudo yum install SDL
```

but I get the following output

```
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit  
google-chrome                                                                   |  951 B     00:00
google-chrome/primary                                                           | 1.4 kB       00:00  
google-chrome                                                                                        3/3  
updates                                                                         | 3.4 kB       00:00  
fedora                                                                          | 2.8 kB         00:00     
Setting up Install Process  
Parsing package install arguments  
Package SDL-1.2.13-7.fc10.i386 already installed and latest version  
Nothing to do
```

I tried googling this error but did not get any help.
I am not able to find what  is the problem could some one help in this ?

Answer (score 2):

SDL_image is a separate module. You need to install its dev package individually. Installing SDL does not install SDL_image as it is an optional piece of the puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

Do a yum install for libpng. Per the [SDL Docs](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/)...

> As of SDL_image 1.2.5, JPEG, PNG, and
>   TIFF image loading libraries are
>   dynamically loaded, so if you don't
>   need to load those formats, you don't
>   need to include those shared
>   libraries. libpng depends on libz, and
>   libtiff depends on both libz and
>   libjpeg.

Comment: Hello Andrew, Thanks for your help. After doing what all you suggested I am still facing the same error. When I examine configure file more closely it executes the following `checking for IMG_LoadPNG_RW in -lSDL_image... no` by calling this code `#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
char IMG_LoadPNG_RW ();
int
main ()
{
return IMG_LoadPNG_RW ();
  ;
  return 0;
} ` and its not able to find reference of the same. :(

Comment: Well, it *should* but you might need to install libpng-dev as well.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who runs into this problem on Ubuntu or an apt-get environment:

sudo apt-get install libpng12-dev libjpeg8-dev libwebp-dev libtiff5-dev

Also, you may be hitting this if you've custom built SDL2 on your machine. In that case you'll also need to rebuild it to add the new features.